# How to extract tag IDs from a list of tags (programatically) in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have what is (probably) a general R question in the framework of creating Shiny reactives. I have included an example below. In the below code I have a list of shiny tags which is passed to the UI. I then wish to extract the tag IDs from this list. How can I do this in the below example in a way that doesn't require hardcoding it?

Many thanks!

```r
## create list of shiny inputs for UI
ids <-  paste0("col", seq(3))
labs <- paste0("label_", seq(3))
foo <- function(x) {colourInput(ids[x], labs[x], "grey")}
my_input <- lapply(seq(ids), foo)
```

This yields a list of shiny tags:

```r
> my_input
[[1]]
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container" data-shiny-input-type="colour">
  <label for="col1">label_1</label>
  <input id="col1" type="text" class="form-control shiny-colour-input" data-init-value="grey" data-show-colour="both" data-palette="square"/>
</div>

[[2]]
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container" data-shiny-input-type="colour">
  <label for="col2">label_2</label>
  <input id="col2" type="text" class="form-control shiny-colour-input" data-init-value="grey" data-show-colour="both" data-palette="square"/>
</div>

[[3]]
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container" data-shiny-input-type="colour">
  <label for="col3">label_3</label>
  <input id="col3" type="text" class="form-control shiny-colour-input" data-init-value="grey" data-show-colour="both" data-palette="square"/>
</div>
```

This is passed as input for the UI.

```r
## shiny app
runApp(shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    my_input,
    plotOutput("plot")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {


    ## ----------- HOW CAN I CREATE cols PROGRAMATICALLY? -----------
    cols <- reactive({
      c(input$col1, input$col2, input$col3)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
       plot(1:10, 1:10, col = c(cols()[1], cols()[2], cols()[3]))
    })
  }
))
```

The variable `cols` in the server above is hardcoded. How can I generate this `reactive` programatically please from the list of tags?

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinythemes_1.1.2    DT_0.13              dplyr_0.8.5          pRoloc_1.29.0       
 [5] BiocParallel_1.22.0  MLInterfaces_1.68.0  cluster_2.1.0        annotate_1.66.0     
 [9] XML_3.99-0.3         AnnotationDbi_1.50.0 IRanges_2.22.1       MSnbase_2.14.0      
[13] ProtGenerics_1.20.0  S4Vectors_0.26.0     mzR_2.22.0           Rcpp_1.0.4.6        
[17] Biobase_2.48.0       BiocGenerics_0.34.0  colourpicker_1.0     shinyjs_1.1         
[21] shiny_1.4.0.2        ggplot2_3.3.0
```

Comment: Since you have the ids in `ids` you can do `sapply(ids, function(id) input[[id]])`. Does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. Indeed this is what I was after and answers the above question.

`sapply(ids, function(id) input[[id]])`